# setting the textbox of an HTML in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

below I am using this script to set a textbox value..

```
    $('#sub').click(function(){

     var num1 = $('#text1').val(); 
     var num2 = $('#text2').val();

     var newVal = (num1+2)*(num2/4);
     var nextVal =(num1+4)*(num2/2);
     $(#text1).val(newVal); //setting the textbox value here
```

Comment: And your question about this is...?

Comment: i just wanted to know if i was correct with the way i tried to set the textbox value in the last statement because it is not working .

Comment: Please provide your HTML code. And check with `console.log` that your code does execute when you click button.

Answer (score 5):

You missed quote marks:

```
$("#text1").val(newVal); //setting the textbox value here
```

It's obvious when you use editor with code highlight support.

Comment: if you mean around the newVal, then i don't think so cuz it has itz own value already..

Comment: even if u add quote marks around #text1, it doesn't still work